# Calling a Void funtion inside a for-loop C++

Tags: c++, function, loops, error-handling

This is my first post on StackOverflow! I'm having an issue with my project for my Intro C++ class. I get an E0349 error, "no operator matches these operands", on my call in the for-loop. I have looked at similar questions on here, but have found no solution. I apologize if I format anything wrong, or don't understand a lot. This is my first class for programming.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void disp2xInt(int num);

int main() {
    // Do "Press any key to continue..." on exit
    atexit([] {system("pause"); });

    // Print out your name and course
    cout << "Jacob" << endl;
    cout << "ELET115N" << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        cout << disp2xInt(i) << "\n";
        cout << "Hello world!!!\n"; 
    }
    disp2xInt(9);

    return 0;
}

void disp2xInt(int n) {
    cout << "2 x " << n;
    cout << " = " << n * 2; 
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `cout` to print in `cout << disp2xInt(i) << "\n";`, when `disp2xInt` returns `void`? Just call it instead `disp2xInt(i)`. Note: I am confident, that there must be a duplicate for it, since I see such a question, every week, but I am too lazy to look for it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `cout` a method returning void. Moreover it's unnecessary in this case since the method itself call `cout` already. Just do :

```
int main() {
    // Do "Press any key to continue..." on exit
    atexit([] {system("pause"); });

    // Print out your name and course
    cout << "Jacob" << endl;
    cout << "ELET115N" << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        disp2xInt(i);
        cout << "Hello world!!!\n"; 
    }
    disp2xInt(9);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, didn't even realize that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int disp2xInt(int num);

int main() {

int x;
// Print out your name and course
cout << "Jacob" << endl;
cout << "ELET115N" << endl << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    x=disp2xInt(i) ;
    cout << x<<endl;;
    cout << "Hello world!!!"<<endl<<endl;
}
disp2xInt(9);

return 0;
}

int disp2xInt(int n) {
cout << "2 x " << n;
cout << " = " << n * 2;
cout << endl;
return n;
}
```

Comment: I like this idea as well. They should both work. Thanks!